# labelled image object doesn't exist

Tags: python, image, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I get the pictures from the wikipedia in a class and add them to the dict, when I want to return it and add the result to the label image, I get an error

```
import tkinter as tk
import urllib.request
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from io import BytesIO
import time

image_dat = {}
class add:
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.test(url)

    def test(self, url):
        if url not in image_dat.keys():
            u = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
            raw_data = u.read()
            u.close()
            im = Image.open(BytesIO(raw_data))
            im = im.resize((25, 25), Image.ANTIALIAS)
            photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
            photo.im = photo
            image_dat[url] = photo
            return image_dat[url]

if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = tk.Tk()
    label = tk.Label()
    label.pack()
    img = add("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fb/Check-Logo.png")
    label['image'] = img
    tk.mainloop()
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y37v9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is because after returning from the `test` function, the image object is not getting returned by the constructor of the `add` class.

For example, just to test, if done like this in the `test` function:

```
.
.
photo.im = photo
image_dat[url] = photo
#if created a label here with that image, it will work fine:
label = tk.Label(root, image=image_dat[url])
label.pack()
```

This way you get no error. This shows everything is fine with the code written inside the `test` function.

---

So, in order to fix the code given in the question:

Since, the constructor `__init__()` can only return None, if you want to return some other object when a class is called, then use the `__new__()` method.

```
.
.
class add:
    def __new__(cls, url):
        return cls.test(url)
      
    def test(url):
        .
        .
```

Using these changes your issue gets solved.